# Entity Framework Return Parent along with child entity as Ieunmerable List

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am new to Entity Framework and had a question i have been stuck on for a while. I have a repository in my DAL to access the data its returning IEnumerable lists for functions defined there. There are two tables involved here table Company and thier Customer_orders please see below for details. I need to return an Ienumerable list for Customer Orders ...which also includes the Customer name. I am able to return everything back for the customer order table but cant get the Customer name from the related table. Is it because I am returning a list of Ienumerable CustomerOrder type? If anyone can provide some help by showing the right code it would be greatly appreciated. Once again I am trying to bind to a grid pulling from the CustomerOrders table but need to also display CustomerName from Customers table.

Table1 (Customers)

company_id

customer_id

customerName

customerAddress

Table 2 (CustomerOrders)

customer_id

product_id

productName

productDesc

This is what I have so far this doesnt pull up any customer Names but pulls the CustomerOrders information

```
 public IEnumerable<CustomerOrders> GetCustomerOrders(int company_id)
    {
       return context.Customers.Where(c => c.company_id == company_id).First().CustomerOrders.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.ProductName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
return  context.CustomerOrders
               .Include(o => o.Customer)
               .Where(o => o.customer_id == customer_id);
```

Comment: Hi broken glass i apologize i think i was trying to setup an example and my description was worong earlier i have updated my description now, I am getting passed a companyID, and that companies orders are in CustomerOrders table. Please see description, I tried your suggestion but didnt work.

Comment: @Shockwave: what part didn't work? Should just have to replace `customer_id` with `company_id` (also I'm missing the OrderBy currently)

Comment: Broken glass, I tried the suggestion you gave me but VS is complaining about the .Include(o => o.Customer) expression it says 'Cannot convert lambda expression to string because its not a delegate type.'

Comment: @Shockwave: Make sure you add a using statement for the `Include` to work: `using System.Data.Entity;` and also add a reference to `System.Data.Entity` to your project